# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 0: ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

After executing of test in NON-GUI Mode getting as:

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 0: ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}
```

and only few samplers are getting pass and remaining samplers are getting failed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAfhN.png)

Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`  as a filename and this is not a valid filename becasue colon `:` cannot be a part of file or directory name.

Your stacktrace is incomplete hence we cannot guess what JMeter component is complaining on the incorrect filename, you need to re-visit all of them which read the data from the file system and ensure that the file names are correct.

We cannot state where the problem is by looking into your Aggregate Report listener, if you want to have more details on failue either amend JMeter's [Result File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) to store request and response data in [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) or add a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and configure what, when and where to store there.

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter)